# Проблемы с Mathcad

Tags: математика, mathcad

помогите решить проблему в Mathcad, я не могу построить 3D фигуры в Mathcad 14, не отображается само поле в котором должны отрисовываться графики. Здесь я нажимаю на значок surface plot, и появляется то что вы ведите на картинке, если я ввожу туда данные, то ничего не происходит.
[image]